# Failed to lookup view \"orders\" in views directory

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, hbs

I'm trying to use `handlebars` with `nodemailer` in order to create a template for emails. Also, I'm trying to get the data from my mongodb database to be able to be displayed on this template. `Nodemailer` is working perfectly fine, but I've never used `handlebars` before, and I keep getting an error saying `failed to lookup view \"orders\" in views directory`. If anyone knows why this could be happening, I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to fix this. Thank you!

mailer.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import hbs from 'nodemailer-express-handlebars';
import Order from './models/orderModel.js';

const mailerRouter = express.Router();

mailerRouter.post (
    '/order', 
expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email
    const orderId = req.body.orderId 
    const em = req.body.em
    const sender = req.body.sender
    const emailBody = await Order.findById(orderId).exec((err, orderData) => {
      if (orderData) {
        res.render('orders', {data:orderData})
      }
    })
    const sub = `Order: ${orderId}`
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: sender,
        pass: '',
        clientId: '',
        clientSecret: '',
        refreshToken: '',
      }
    })
   
    transporter.use('compile', hbs({
      viewEngine: 'express-handlebars',
      viewPath:'./views/'
    }))
        const mailOptions = {
        from: sender, 
        to: em, 
        subject: sub, 
        text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
        template: 'orders',
      }
      console.log(mailOptions.subject)
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
        if(err)
          console.log(err)
        else
          console.log(info);
     });
  
}))

export default mailerRouter;
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';
import hbs from 'express-handlebars';
import returnRouter from './routers/returnRouter.js';
import mailerRouter from './mailer.js';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors()); //and thisnp
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/AM', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
});


app.use('/api/orders', orderRouter);
app.use('/api/mailer', mailerRouter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is ready');
});

app.engine('hbs', hbs({
    defaultLayout: 'template',
    extname: '.hbs',
}));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

orders.hbs (within a views folder)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {{#each data.orderItems}}
    <div>
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</body>
</html>
```

Directory

```
- backend
    |-- modeles
    |     | -- orderModel.js
    |     | -- ... other files
    |
    |
    |-- routes
    |    | -- orderRoutes.js
    |    | -- ... other files
    |
    | 
    |-- views
    |    | -- orders.hbs       
    |
    | -- server.js
    | -- mailer.js
    | -- utils.js
    | ... other files
- frontend
    | -- other directories
```

Comment: I think it would help if you shared the structure of your views/ directory. It sounds like `orders` is not at the root and so you need to change the path in your `res.render` call.

Comment: @76484 Hi, okay, I added my backend directory to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but my next guess is that the `viewPath:'./views/'` in your `transporter.use` call is pointing to the wrong place. Perhaps you need to use `__dirname + '/views'` as you do in server.js?

Comment: so I ended up changing ```app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');``` to```app.set('views', path.join( __dirname, '/backend/views'));``` and that seems to have solved this problem, but the template is still not showing on the emails, so now I have to figure that out. Thank you for your help